# Sorting an array of objects by a property which may be missing

Tags: javascript, performance, array, sorting, ecmascript-6

## Problem

I am sorting an array of objects. Each element may have a property called `reference` or it may be `undefined`. When defined, it is a user-provided string (which is why I use [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)).

If the `reference` is not available, that element's relative position in the final list is irrelevant save that all blank references must appear grouped together at the end.

## Implementation

```
function sort(searchResult) {
    const hasReference = searchResult
        .filter(taskCard => typeof taskCard.reference !== "undefined");

    const missingReference = searchResult
        .filter(taskCard => typeof taskCard.reference === "undefined");

    hasReference.sort(
        (tc1, tc2) => tc1.reference.localeCompare(tc2.reference)
    );

    return hasReference.concat(missingReference);
}
```

## My Concerns

1. Is this an efficient way of solving this problem in terms of *time*?
2. I'm currently iterating over the initial array twice. Is there an elegant ES6 way to do this in a single pass that I'm not seeing?
3. I believe *memory* to be less of a concern (because I exactly double the amount of memory used while processing by generating two new arrays that together are the size of the original); am I correct?
4. Are there any scalability pitfalls doing it this way?
5. As usual, any other comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this an efficient way of solving this problem in terms of *time*?

The filtering steps have time complexity \$O(n)\$,
and the sorting step has \$O(n \log n)\$.
Even if the filtering may look a bit of a waste,
the dominant operation is the sort,
*if most of the items have the `reference` property*.

> I'm currently iterating over the initial array twice. Is there an elegant ES6 way to do this in a single pass that I'm not seeing?

Yes, you could implement the compare method in a way that items with `undefined` value as the property get sorted at the end,
as [@igor-soloydenko](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10983/igor-soloydenko) did in his answer.

> I believe *memory* to be less of a concern (because I exactly double the amount of memory used while processing by generating two new arrays that together are the size of the original); am I correct?

Extra \$O(n)\$ memory doesn't seem a big concern.
If it is, then you can use the in-place alternative,
that doesn't use extra memory.
More or less, see the next point.

> Are there any scalability pitfalls doing it this way?

The only scalability pitfall that I see is the extra \$O(n)\$ memory,
in case of very large input.

The fact that you partition the input has the interesting effect that if a large portion of the input has `undefined` values,
the sorting step will be faster using the current technique compared to the in-place alternative,
because the items with `undefined` values will not be part of the slow sort operation.
If you don't expect many `undefined` values,
then the in-place technique should be faster.

Comment: "the sorting step will be faster using the current technique compared to the in-place alternative in a previous point" this is part of the reason I split the input. In my _test data_ a large portion is `undefined`; however, it remains to be seen if this will be the case in production.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a single-pass example. Very similar to @janos' code (which has a good complexity analysis). The only difference is in how various cases with `undefined` are treated.

```
function sort(searchResult) {
  return searchResult.sort((tc1, tc2) => {

    const tc1RefUndefined = tc1.reference == null;
    const tc2RefUndefined = tc2.reference == null;
    if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined) {
      if (tc1RefUndefined && tc2RefUndefined) {
        return 0;

        // or if consistency in grouping (within the groups) is necessary:
        // return tc1.otherProperty comparedTo tc2.otherProperty
      } else if (tc1RefUndefined) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }

    return tc1.reference.localeCompare(tc2.reference);
  });
}
```

Comment: @msanford this is true. Fixed now. I'd rather use `const tc1RefUndefined = typeof tc1.reference == null;` though, because in _most_ (not all) cases `null` and `undefined` may be treated as the same thing. This detail is specific to a particular app implementation.

Comment: I meant `const tc1RefUndefined = tc1.reference == null;` lol

Answer (score 1):

A a bit more cryptic but shorter variation of the solution by @IgorSoloydenko could be:

```
function sort(searchResult) {
  return searchResult.sort((tc1, tc2) => {

    const tc1RefUndefined = tc1.reference == null ? 1 : 0;
    const tc2RefUndefined = tc2.reference == null ? 1 : 0;

    if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined) {
      return tc1RefUndefined - tc2RefUndefined;
    }

    return tc1.reference.localeCompare(tc2.reference);
  });
}
```

Comment: If both tc1's and tc2's `references` are set to `null/undefined`, we get tc1RefUndefined == tc2RefUndefined == 0. The instructions under `if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined)` will not get executed therefore, which [I think] is a bug. Moreover, it will let the `tc1.reference.localeCompare(tc2.reference)` get executed, that will result in a "Can't get `localeCompare` of null/undefined".

Comment: I think, you need to do `const tc1RefUndefined = tc1.reference == null ? 1 : 0;` and  `const tc2RefUndefined = tc2.reference == null ? 1 : 0;` and then `return tc2RefUndefined - tc1RefUndefined;` maybe? I really like the commonly applied idea of subtracting numeric fields for comparison. The issue is that cryptic implementations are less readable and bug prone. This can be improved a bit with a good set of unit tests, but I don't know whether it worth it.

Comment: Oops, yes, I accidently swapped the values. I've edited it. Thanks.